# Image resize issue on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, image

I have the following situation:

I have set my images size for single page in `view.xml` let say 2000x2000

```
    <width>2000</width>
   <height>2000</height>
```

The image now is ok, and is 2000x2000.

My problem:

If a will upload a image with 1200x800, or another values the images look stretch or small and looks really wierd.

Is there a solution to avoid the resize? or can be set a "auto" value in view xml?

What i want, is to upload a picutres, and afert this I want the original size to be shown on the page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
For single page image I found the function that load the pictures and I modified this function to load the pictures with the real size, without having to resize anything.

This is my function:

```
namespace namespace\Resize\Block\Catalog\Product\View;

class Gallery extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery
{

   public function getGalleryImagesJson()
    {   
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $imagesItems = [];
        foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $image) {
            //change the path of the photo for the single product 
            $imagesItems[] = [
                'thumb' => $this->getBaseUrl().'pub/media/catalog/product/'.$image['file'],
                'img' => $this->getBaseUrl().'pub/media/catalog/product/'.$image['file'],
                'full' => $this->getBaseUrl().'pub/media/catalog/product/'.$image['file'],
                'caption' => $image->getLabel(),
                'position' => $image->getPosition(),
                'isMain' => $this->isMainImage($image),
            ];
        }
        if (empty($imagesItems)) {
            $imagesItems[] = [
                'thumb' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('thumbnail'),
                'img' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image'),
                'full' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image'),
                'caption' => '',
                'position' => '0',
                'isMain' => true,
            ];
        }
        return json_encode($imagesItems);
    }

}
```

and my **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">       
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery">
        <plugin name="plugin_block_catalog_product_view_gallery"
                type="namespace\Resize\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Gallery"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
 </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help because I have a different version, but if you go into you

```
System > Configuration > Theme settings > Category view/Images
```

Make sure you have yes for **"Keep Image Aspect Ratio"** - "Image aspect ratio size" to square rectangle and set the image width (recommended 270) and height (recommended 365), this should help without you having to resize any images.